# Subscript out of range - PQ refresh

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

So I don't know how I get a "Subscript out of range" on this line of code.  It worked last week, a different input file but the same line of code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Fixed Price").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
```

Comment: Fewer columns than before?

Comment: That means you have no connection named *Query - Fixed Price* in the active workbook.

Comment: The funny thing is that it is in the Data Connections, and was, there last week.  The query exists!  This code has existed for months.  It just stopped working today.

Comment: Peter, nope.  Same columns.  The data goes out 10 years so it is I from Sept 22 to Aug 23.  Same last week, I just checked.  Also, this line of code is just turning off the background refresh.  I don't think it looks at the data, only the query options.

Comment: No, there is no connection with that name in the active workbook. Maybe the active workbook isn't the one you think it is. `Dim conn As WorkbookConnection`, `For Each conn in ActiveWorkbook.Connections`, `Debug.Print conn.Name`, `Next`. Then inspect the output in the Immediate Window.

Comment: Delete the line of code . Write it new. Sounds stupid but helped me in the past with this problem…